# shareaholic share buttons not loading

Tags: javascript, html, aurelia

I am trying to use share buttons from http://www.shareaholic.com, but I having issues with loading the buttons on elements loading asynchronously.
First of all, the following code works on a static page.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' 
            src='//dsms0mj1bbhn4.cloudfront.net/assets/pub/shareaholic.js' 
            data-shr-siteid='000000000000000000000000000000000' 
            data-cfasync='false' 
            async='async'>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <! -- this loads fine -->
    <div class='shareaholic-canvas' data-app='share_buttons' data-app-id='99999999'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But if there is an element that loads asynchronously, it doesn't load the share buttons.

```html
##### index.html ######
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' 
            src='//dsms0mj1bbhn4.cloudfront.net/assets/pub/shareaholic.js' 
            data-shr-siteid='000000000000000000000000000000000' 
            data-cfasync='false' 
            async='async'>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- this section gets loaded after index.html loaded -->
    <blog-content></blog-content>
  </body>
</html>

##### blog-content.html #####
<template>
  <!-- some blog content here -->
  <div class='shareaholic-canvas' data-app='share_buttons' data-app-id='99999999'></div>
</template>
```

I am guessing that is because  section gets executed before  section finish loading, but I am not sure what would be the best way to handle this situation. I am using Aurelia.js as a framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script tag that loads shareaholic.js has the `async` attribute so it will execute asynchronously and won't block the rest of the page load.

While shareaholic.js is loading aurelia has the opportunity to start up and replace the content of the `<body>` element with the aurelia app.

By the time shareaholic.js has loaded the "shareaholic-canvas" div no longer exists in the dom.

You might try creating a shareaholic custom element like this:

**shareaholic.html**

```html
<template>
  <script type='text/javascript' 
          src='//dsms0mj1bbhn4.cloudfront.net/assets/pub/shareaholic.js' 
          data-shr-siteid='000000000000000000000000000000000' 
          data-cfasync='false' 
          async='async'>
  </script>
  <div class='shareaholic-canvas' data-app='share_buttons' data-app-id='99999999'></div>
</template>
```

And then using the custom attribute like this:

**app.html**

```html
<template>
  <require from="shareaholic.html"></require>

  <shareaholic></shareaholic>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' 
            src='//dsms0mj1bbhn4.cloudfront.net/assets/pub/shareaholic.js' 
            data-shr-siteid='000000000000000000000000000000000' 
            data-cfasync='false' 
            async='async'>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <! -- this loads fine -->
    <div class='shareaholic-canvas' data-app='share_buttons' data-app-id='99999999'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```